# My Animated character won't render at all

Tags: rendering, animation

My animated character is clearly marked to render and appears perfectly fine in the camera but simply wont render. I can't figure it out.
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: He's done that.  As odd as it seems, the simple question is sufficient to explain the problem:  if you open the blend file and hit F12, you see the floor but not the character, i.e. "character won't render at all".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a surprisingly difficult one.

Somewhere along the line, Blender was told that your armature should have instancing enabled for vertices.  Without explaining what that means, (see below for explanation) here is the solution:

- Enter object mode
- Select the armature
- Go to *Object Properties* in the *Properties Editor*
- Go to the *Instancing Tab*
- Select *none*

[image: Instancing with none selected]

You also have a problem with scaling not being properly set, but it doesn't seem to affect the animation.

Explanation: *Instancing* is a blender feature where the object is used as a template for what to display, rather than being what is displayed.  In your file, it was set to *Vertices* for the armature.  This means that each vertex of the armature was to be replaced by a different object and that different object displayed.  The problem is that no different object was provided, so nothing was displayed.

I think your import was screwed up, but this should fix it.